# how can't I update my user profile with new information?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee-6

I want to update my user profile if the `String loginExist = null` or `loginExist.equals(principal.getName())`

the problem is that I get NullPointerException.

this is my code:

```
// update profile
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateRH", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateRH(Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("user") user user) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    String loginExist = "";
    user rh = RhRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    try {
        loginExist = userRepo.findCountUsername(user.getUsername());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println(loginExist);

    if (loginExist.equals(null) || loginExist.equals(principal.getName())) {
        user.setId(RhRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName()).getId());
        user.setPwd(encoder.encode(user.getPwd()));
        RhRepo.save(user);
    } else {
        String msg = "Username Deja exist !!!";
        mv.addObject("msg", msg);
    }

    mv.addObject("rh", rh);
    mv.setViewName("rhprofile");
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: your code is not null safe and lots of lines might cause this problem. which line do you get the exception?

Comment: loginExist = userRepo.findCountUsername(user.getUsername()); this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loginExist.equals(null) will throw NPE if loginExist is null as you are trying to call a method from a null object.

Use :-

loginExist == null

instead.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is `user.getUsername()`. the `user` is null and trying to get its `username` causes a NullPointerWxception.

add a check before that call, try this:

```
if (user != null) {
    loginExist = userRepo.findCountUsername(user.getUsername());
}
```

otherwise (if it is null), you need to create the user before trying to find it from repository.